# Unwanted white bar below the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers, vc1 and vc2. From vc1 I go to vc2, inside vc2 I play a youtube video using web view. When I come back to vc1 I get a white bar below my screen. This is my code.

```
/* From App Delegate to go vc1 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    VC1 *vc1 = [[VC1 alloc] init];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navigationController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [navigationController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
    [navigationController pushViewController:vc1 animated:FALSE];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

/* From VC1 to VC2 */
-(IBAction)gotoVC2:(id)sender
{
    VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.navigationController vc2 animated:YES];
}

/* Setting up YouTube View */
-(void) addYouTubeLink:(UIWebView*)webView url:(NSString*)url
{
    for (UIView* shadowView in [webView.scrollView subviews])
    {
        if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [shadowView setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
    NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" align=\"middle\" frameborder=\"1\"></iframe></body></html>",url];
    [webView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
}
/* Going Back to VC1 */
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [appDelegate.navigationController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
    [appDelegate.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Please see the screenshot attached for the white bar below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure this has anything to do with your problem, but you shouldn't be accessing the app delegate to get the navigation controller from either VC1 or VC2. You should use self.navigationController push ....

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing your navigation controller with a root view controller.

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it why you use appDelegate.navigation controller, because you can initiate navigation controller with  rootViewController, and push and pop another controller if you want.

But focusing to your situation, I think it's about `frame problem`. in your `goback:sender` method, after `popViewControllerAnimated:` adjust `vc1's frame` the way you want. To do this, I think you should `retain` vc1 controller in your code. like

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *vc1;
```

in your header, and

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
           VC1 *vc1 = [[VC1 alloc] init];
           self.vc1 = vc1;
```

I hope it helps :)